# How to iterate a python list and compare items in a string or another list

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

Following my earlier question, I have tried to work on a code to return a string if a search term in a certain list is in a string to be returned as follows.

```
import re
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
def foo():
    List1 = ['risk','cancer','ocp','hormone','OCP',]
    txt = "Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized. Breast cancer is 100 times more frequent in women than in men.\
    Factors associated with an increased exposure to estrogen have also been elucidated including early menarche, late menopause, later age\
    at first pregnancy, or nulliparity. The use of hormone replacement therapy has been confirmed as a risk factor, although mostly limited to \
    the combined use of estrogen and progesterone, as demonstrated in the WHI (2). Analysis showed that the risk of breast cancer among women using \
    estrogen and progesterone was increased by 24% compared to placebo. A separate arm of the WHI randomized women with a prior hysterectomy to \
    conjugated equine estrogen (CEE) versus placebo, and in that study, the use of CEE was not associated with an increased risk of breast cancer (3).\
    Unlike hormone replacement therapy, there is no evidence that oral contraceptive (OCP) use increases risk. A large population-based case-control study \
    examining the risk of breast cancer among women who previously used or were currently using OCPs included over 9,000 women aged 35 to 64 \
    (half of whom had breast cancer) (4). The reported relative risk was 1.0 (95% CI, 0.8 to 1.3) among women currently using OCPs and 0.9 \
    (95% CI, 0.8 to 1.0) among prior users. In addition, neither race nor family history was associated with a greater risk of breast cancer among OCP users."
    words = txt
    corpus = " ".join(words).lower()
    sentences1 = sent_tokenize(corpus)
    a = [" ".join([sentences1[i-1],j]) for i,j in enumerate(sentences1) if [item in List1] in word_tokenize(j)]   


    for i in a:
        print i,'\n','\n'

foo()
```

The problem is that the python IDLE does not print anything. What could I have done wrong. What it does is run the code  and I get this

> >
>   >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear to me so please correct me if i'm getting this wrongly. Are you trying to match the list of keywords (in list1) against the text (in txt)? That is,

- For each keyword in list1
- Do a match against every sentences in txt.
- Print the sentence if they matches?

Instead of writing a complicated regular expression to solve your problem I have broken it down into 2 parts.

First I break the whole lot of text into a list of sentences. Then write simple regular expression to go through every sentences. Trouble with this approach is that it is not very efficient but hey it solves your problem.

Hope this small chunk of code can help guide you to the real solution.

```
def foo():
    List1 = ['risk','cancer','ocp','hormone','OCP',]
    txt = "blah blah blah - truncated"
    words = txt

    matches = []
    sentences = re.split(r'\.', txt)
    keyword = List1[0]
    pattern = keyword 
    re.compile(pattern)

    for sentence in sentences:
        if re.search(pattern, sentence):
            matches.append(sentence)

    print("Sentence matching the word (" + keyword + "):")
    for match in matches:
        print (match)
```

--------- Generate random number -----

```
from random import randint

List1 = ['risk','cancer','ocp','hormone','OCP',]
print(randint(0, len(List1) - 1)) # gives u random index - use index to access List1
```

Comment: You Have done me a lot of Favor!!! Thank you!! IT WORKS. Though I would like to work of a way that would select items from List1 randomly instead of e.g. List1[0] or List1[3]

Comment: Maybe try:

from random import randint. I have updated the solution to include a sample code.

Comment: Great. Works with keyword = List1[(randint(0, len(List1) - 1))]....also works with a while loop